# Using RFECV on RandomForestRegressor for a regression problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

Im trying to use REFCV to identify optimum features from 122 features (13783 rows).  The data is continuous data and I'm trying to identify the most significant features WRT the target variable.  Ive done the usual train/test split (80:20).  But, it seems when i run my code it takes forever with no results so i have to stop it.

I have an apple mac pro 2015
Processor :2.7 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
Memory: 8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3

below is my code:

```
#Importing libraries
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
%matplotlib inline


RF = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)

# Using RFECV to find the optimum number of best features
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=RF, cv=4)

#Fitting Train data and timing
%%time
rfecv.fit(X_train, y_train)

rfecv.grid_scores_

#Plotting the number of features to visualise optimum number of features
num_features = X_train.shape
num_features[1]

plt.figure(figsize=[10, 5])
plt.plot(range(1, num_features[1]+1), rfecv.grid_scores_)
plt.show()

#features
rfecv.n_features_
```

Answer (score 1):

RFECV is a repetitive process, it fits multiple times on your data to get best features. The best you can do is to run it on multiple CPU cores to make it faster, using this code:

```
RF = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, n_jobs = -1)
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=RF, cv=4, verbose = 1, n_jobs = -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting the 'step', and "min_features_to_select" parameter.
Refer: [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html)